# An option must be a rule or a list of rules

Tags: plotting

What is wrong with it?

```
f[x_] := 2^x + 7x - 10

Plot[f[x], {x, -4, 8}, AxesOrigin \[RightArrow] {0, 0}]
```

> Plot::nonopt: Options expected (instead of
> AxesOrigin[RightArrow]{0,0}) beyond position 2 in
> Plot[f[x],{x,-4,8},AxesOrigin[RightArrow]{0,0}]. An option must be a
> rule or a list of rules.

Comment: `Plot[f[x], {x, -4, 8}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]` : A backslash  is missing before `\[RightArrow]`.

Comment: @syed `\[Rule]` is not `\[RightArrow]`. This is a common mistake among beginners, because they click the wrong button in math assistant. The backslash doesn't display because OP hasn't use code blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I typed it as `-` and `>` after a few attempts and was wondering.

Comment: @xzczd Thank you, didn't know about this difference between arrows, we used to just copy everything from word doc without explainings. Now problem is solved, thx!